# Modifying #define value between each run

Tags: c++

Let's assume I have a simple code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define index 5

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int bar = atoi(argv[0]);
int foo[index];

//Some code to fill in values of array.
printf("%d",array[0]);

// Some code that executes functions related with bar
}
```

So lets assume I run this code with a `.sh` file with the following lines
`./run 5;./run 10;./run 15`

What I want to achieve is like the `bar` variable, changing the value of define between in each run without opening the file and modifying it by myself.

Is there any easy way to modify the `#define` value with a script in between in each run with `.sh` file ?

I can't make it a argument to pass to main because the array definition gives error saying it needs constant value. Although I tried `const int` there was no luck.

Comment: You can pass compiler definitions at compile time if what you mean by "run" is that.

Comment: "I can't make it a argument to pass to main because the array definition gives error saying it needs constant value." just use `std::vector` instead of array.

Comment: *Always* check that the user passes the arguments you expect before using `argv[i]` (for any valid value of `i`). And remember that `argv[0]` is the command "name", not the first arguments. Lastly `atoi` is not good at detecting errors, and problems and it will return `0`. Use `std::stoi` or `std::strtol` instead.

Comment: Note that it is a bad practice to use a #define as a constant in the first place however since you don't actually want it to be a constant since you want it to vary at runtime the correct `c++` answer is to use a dynamic array and the `c++` dynamic array is std::vector

Comment: Thank  you for your valuable answers for me to understand better, for the second part of the question is it possible to modify parts of code between each run with a script ?

Comment: It's possible to write a script that modifies the code, recompiles it, and then runs the resulting executable, but it's usually a bad idea for C++. Especially in this situation where your design really doesn't _need_ the varying parameter to be a compile-time constant for any given execution

Answer (score 0):

```
#define CONST VAL
```

The only thing #define does in this case is replace all occurrences of the word CONST with VAL. This is done by the **precompiler**

To actually change the value in the definition you need to recompile it.

If you don't want to edit the source each time, you can give arguments to the compiler to define the value:

```
g++ -Dindex=5
```

Though in your use case I think recompiling each time the program is ran isn't really a better user experience than just defining a vector and limiting its size.